# JQuery DatePicker set default date on page load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using 2 JQueryUI Date Pickers for an application where I am using ajax to post the dates to a back end MySQL database.  The first datepicker is used to post the initial date.  The second datepicker is used to post the modified date.

I am having an issue when a user does not select a date from the date picker, in either instance.  This is due to the onSelect function being used to retrieve the date value which is passed to ajax to post in the MySQL db.

I believe I need to define default date values for both datepickers when the page loads, so that if the user has not selected a date it will not be undefined when it gets passed to the AJAX to post.

What is the best way to do this?

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        inline: true,
        //nextText: '&rarr;',
        //prevText: '&larr;',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        //showOn: "button",
        //buttonImage: "img/calendar-blue.png",
        //buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            reservationDate = $(".datepicker[name=datepicker1]").val();
            modifyDate = $(".datepicker[name=datepicker2]").val();
            }
    });
});
</script>

<input type="text" class='datepicker' name="datepicker1" />
<input type="text" class='datepicker' name="datepicker2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is putting the default date on the text field.

```
<input type="text" class='datepicker' name="datepicker1" value="01/01/2013" />
```

I don't know if this is the best on your scenario.

Comment: @AndrewGibson `defaultDate` doesn't fill in the form field until the datepicker is opened.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar . I deleted my comment as others have answered the question. Andy.

Answer (score 0):

Just create your inputs with the date that you want to set:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" name="datepicker1" value="Your date Here" />
```

jQuery UI datepicker also allows you to specify a [default date](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate).

Or in your AJAX request, replace the null value with the date you want to POST.